# String input in Forth

Tags: forth

I need a user to input two words from the keyboard and then do things with their letters. I found this example in a book and it works for one word, but when I try to enter two words, I immediately get `:  Stack underflow >invitation<`

I'm really new to Forth. I've tried to find examples in books, but I couldn't. How can I solve my problem?

```
CREATE word1 14 ALLOT
: .wordik1 word1 14 -TRAILING TYPE ;
: .getword1 word1 14 BLANK word1 14 EXPECT ;

CREATE word2 15 ALLOT
: .wordik2 word2 15 -TRAILING TYPE ;
: .getword2 word2 15 BLANK word2 EXPECT ;


: invitation
  ." First word:" CR
  .getword1
  ." Second word:" CR
  .getword2
  ;
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the buffer length in arguments to `EXPECT` in `.getword2`

Comment: omg why i am like this:D thanks